# The component for route app must be a react component

Tags: navigation-drawer, react-native, react-component

I have below code base

Getting this error

**The component for route app must be a react component**

I saw many questions like this on SO, and solutions there but being a beginner not able to resolve yet, tried with adding export / export default with each class
but not working

https://snack.expo.io/@mparvez19861/drawer-navigation?session_id=snack-session-hyLuO4xPa

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableHighlight, Image } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  AsyncStorage,
  Button,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from
  'react-navigation';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'

class HeaderNavigationBar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{
        height: 70,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'center'
      }}>
        <TouchableHighlight style={{ marginLeft: 10, marginTop: 15 }}
          onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.openDrawer() }}>
          {/* <Image
style={{ width: 32, height: 32 }}
source={{uri: 'https://png.icons8.com/ios/2x/menu-filled.png'}}
/> */}
          <Icon name='md-menu' size={35} />

        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export class HomeScreen extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
      }}>

        <HeaderNavigationBar {...this.props} />
        <View style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: '#4885ed',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center'
        }}>

          <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 22, color: 'white' }}>
            This is Home Screen
        </Text>

        </View>
      </View>);
  }
}

export class InfoScreen extends Component {

  render() {
    return (<View style={{
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'column',
    }}>
      <HeaderNavigationBar {...this.props} />
      <View style={{
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#4734ac',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
      }}>
        <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 22, color: 'white' }}>
          This is Info Screen
</Text>

      </View>
    </View>);
  }

}
class SignInScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Please sign in',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title="Sign in!" onPress={this._signInAsync} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  _signInAsync = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', 'abc');
    this.props.navigation.navigate('App');
  };
}

class AuthLoadingScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._bootstrapAsync();
  }

  // Fetch the token from storage then navigate to our appropriate place
  _bootstrapAsync = async () => {
    const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');

    // This will switch to the App screen or Auth screen and this loading
    // screen will be unmounted and thrown away.
    this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'App' : 'Auth');
  };

  // Render any loading content that you like here
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ActivityIndicator />
        <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({ SignIn: SignInScreen });

const drNav = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen
    },
    Info: {
      screen: InfoScreen
    }
  }
)

export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    App: drNav,
    Auth: AuthStack,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
));

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Is this your actual code? Make sure all your components are being exported and imported correctly. Also, could you post the error's stacktrace? Do you have any idea what component is throwing the error? Or what to do in order to reproduce this error?

I copied your code to a new Snack in Expo and it runs just fine.. no error at all.

Comment: This is what I am trying now .. https://snack.expo.io/@mparvez19861/drawer-navigation?session_id=snack-session-hyLuO4xPa

Comment: Could you try creating a new Snack and pasting your code inside App.js? Don't remove anything else.

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@mparvez19861/cmFudG

Comment: Now getting diff error

Comment: As I said, I'm running your exact code (copy pasted) and it works just fine in Expo -> https://imgur.com/a/Ylq4weH

Comment: @josemigallas, can I have your snack link

Comment: const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({
  // { SignIn: SignInScreen }
  SignIn: { screen: SignInScreen }
  });  this is not in your snack

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191156/discussion-between-josemigallas-and-md-parvez-alam).